# Where is the best place to do data aggregation for UI in microservices architecture

Tags: rest, microservices, single-page-application, api-design

I am building an application using microservice architecture. It has five Rest API and one UI(single page application) microservices.

[image]

Could anyone advise me which is the best option to do the data aggregation?

1. Make UI application as a static web application and do all API requests from the front end (from the browser using JavaScript framework) and all data aggregation do in front end itself and render?
2. Make UI application as a dynamic web application and do all API request and data aggregation in web application backend?

Comment: As always it depends, I would use option no 2 with an Api gateway that would handle some concerns like authentication and https termination

Comment: Which scenario is the best use case for option 1?

Comment: Option 1 is good if you do not have authentication or you don't want to monitor the health of the microservices or you don't use loadbalancing, don't use rate limiting etc (all of these can be used with option 1 but is harder). See here the advantages or cases when to use an API Gateway http://microservices.io/patterns/apigateway.html

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like the pattern you are looking for is [API Gateway](http://microservices.io/patterns/apigateway.html). Sometimes also called "Edge" or "EdgeService". It can be used to as a single entrypoint to your cluster and to aggregate service call results. Other use cases include central authentication and/or authorization as well as routing, monitoring and resiliency.

Some people only route external calls through a gateway, others route also internal calls through the gateway.

Here some technologies to look into:

[Zuul](https://github.com/Netflix/zuul/wiki) from the Netflix stack. You have write a filter for aggregation. See [this](https://github.com/Netflix/zuul/wiki/Writing-Filters) document.

[Amazon API gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/) - If you are running on AWS. You would typically use your own lambda service for aggregation.

[Kong](https://getkong.org/about/). Doesn't have native aggregation support, but you can forward to a separate aggregation service that you provide.

Comment: If microservice platform has multiple UI, dose it has to use multiple API Gateway?     If I use API Gateway as a my UI data aggregator  every time if I do a change on my Rest API microservice I have to do a change on API Gateway.    Then I have to deploy as well. Also It can be become bottle neck and single point of failure. I agree that API Gateway can use central authentication and/or authorization and routing and monitoring of my API.

Comment: API gateway is not supposed to change when one of the aggregated services changes if you implement it right. Multiple UIs for me just means you serve a few different sets of (static) javascript libraries to the client. If there is overlap in which services the UIs use then I would expect to have client bindings not replicated but shared as dependencies in those javascript libraries.

Comment: Thanks for answer. According to your answer I feel like best way to address this to create a static web application and communicate the Rest APIs through API gateway. With out have web application backend. In this case there will be no backend in web application. only consist of client side javascript for UI. is it good approach ?

Comment: If you don't have a backend, then you don't need an api gateway either of course!